# ember.js context aware handlebars helper

Tags: ember.js

I have code like this that I am going to repeat a lot:

```
<div>
  {{#if sender.isContact}}
  <a {{action showContact sender href=true}}>{{unbound sender.displayName}}</a>
  {{else}}
    <a {{action showUser sender href=true}}>{{unbound sender.displayName}}</a>
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

THe only bit that changes is the action that the will be called.

How would I create a handlebars helper method to dry this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The creation of custom helpers is described pretty well in the [Templates section of the Ember.js Guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/).

You can also have a look at how the `{{action}}` helper [in the Code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/helpers/action.js#L231-L263) and merge the parts you need for your own helper.